# jquery-ui modal form validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

The query-ui modal validation documentation states that validation does not begin until form submission.

I want to have validation begin almost immediately without the need for the first submission.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use setInterval()

So my form named "testForm" would have:

setInternal($('#testForm').valid(), 5000);

The valid() test is run every 5 seconds and forces validation without form submission etc.